# Does Vim have any hidden "easter eggs" or jokes? If so, which?

Tags: help-system, undocumented-behaviour

I've heard rumours about Vim having some hidden "easter eggs" and jokes. Is this true? What are they?

Answer (score 4):

[Vim is surreallist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images). From [`:help bar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#bar):

```
|           To screen column [count] in the current line.
            |exclusive| motion.  Ceci n'est pas une pipe.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do the dishes with Vim. From [`:help howdoi`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/howto.txt.html):

```
|You can't! (yet)|  do dishes using Vim
```

Comment: This is (probably) in reference to a cleaning product named "vim" that was quite common in the Netherlands (AFAIK it doesn't exist any more).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Oh, don't worry about that. Vim is alive and kicking in India (where I am). :D

Answer (score 3):

```
:help!
E478: Don't panic!
```

Not in big friendly letters on the cover though

Answer (score 3):

```
:Ni!
```

```
Do you demand a shrubbery?
```

Answer (score 3):

Vim understands that nuns can live in monasteries too. [`:help map-modes`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-modes):

```
:nunmap can also be used outside of a monastery.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:help 42
```

```
What is the meaning of life, the universe and everything?  42
Douglas Adams, the only person who knew what this question really was about
is now dead, unfortunately.  So now you might wonder what the meaning of
death is...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:help UserGettingBored
```

```
                                                        UserGettingBored
UserGettingBored                When the user presses the same key 42 times.
                                Just kidding! :-)
```

Older versions of Vim (7.2?) actually seem to have had a different description for this:

```
:help UserGettingBored
```

```
                            *UserGettingBored*
UserGettingBored        When the user hits CTRL-C.  Just kidding! :-)
```

Comment: So, would it actually get triggered by pressing the same key 42 times?

Comment: @Wildcard No, there are no references to this in the Vim source outside of the documentation files.